# Why "[ 1 > 2 ]" evaluates to True?

Tags: linux, bash

I have two files:
f1.txt:

```
1
```

dest/f1.txt:

```
1
2
```

When I run `wc -l` on both of those files in linux terminal - I get my expected results:

```
$ wc -l < f1.txt
$ 1
$ wc -l < dest/f1.txt
$ 2
```

But when I run the following .sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash

    if [ $(wc -l < f1.txt) > $(wc -l < dest/f1.txt) ]; then
        echo -e "f1 has more lines"
    else
        echo -e "f1 doesn't have more lines"
    fi
```

The output is:

```
f1 has more lines
```

Can you explian how could this be possible?

Comment: Use `-gt` instead of `>`

Comment: Use `(( ... ))` instead of `[ ... ]` for arithmetic.

Comment: Note that if you *did* want to use `>` (for string comparison), you need to escape it to prevent it from being treated as a redirection operator, since `[` is a regular command, not special syntax. You should have a new file with a numerical name in your directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the `-gt` for **integer comparison** in a `if` clause.

If you use `>` or `<` you will end up doing **ASCII alphabetic order comparison**.

**integer comparison**

`-eq`
is equal to

```
if [ "$a" -eq "$b" ]
```

`-ne`
is not equal to

```
if [ "$a" -ne "$b" ]
```

`-gt`
is greater than

```
if [ "$a" -gt "$b" ]
```

`-ge`
is greater than or equal to

```
if [ "$a" -ge "$b" ]
```

`-lt`
is less than

```
if [ "$a" -lt "$b" ]
```

`-le`
is less than or equal to

```
if [ "$a" -le "$b" ]
```

`<`
is less than (**within double parentheses**)

```
(("$a" < "$b"))
```

`<=`
is less than or equal to (**within double parentheses**)

```
(("$a" <= "$b"))
```

`>`
is greater than (**within double parentheses**)

```
(("$a" > "$b"))
```

`>=`
is greater than or equal to (**within double parentheses**)

```
(("$a" >= "$b"))
```

**string comparison**

`=`
is equal to

```
if [ "$a" = "$b" ]
```

**Caution

Note the whitespace framing the `=`.**

```
if [ "$a"="$b" ] is not equivalent to the above.
```

`==`
is equal to

```
if [ "$a" == "$b" ]
```

This is a synonym for `=`.

```
Note    
The == comparison operator behaves differently within a double-brackets test than within single brackets.
[[ $a == z* ]]   # True if $a starts with an "z" (pattern matching).
[[ $a == "z*" ]] # True if $a is equal to z* (literal matching).

[ $a == z* ]     # File globbing and word splitting take place.
[ "$a" == "z*" ] # True if $a is equal to z* (literal matching).
```

`!=`
is not equal to

```
if [ "$a" != "$b" ]
```

This operator uses pattern matching within a `[[ ... ]]` construct.

`<`
is less than, in ASCII alphabetical order

```
if [[ "$a" < "$b" ]]

if [ "$a" \< "$b" ]
```

Note that the `"<"` needs to be escaped within a `[ ]` construct.

`>`
is greater than, in ASCII alphabetical order

```
if [[ "$a" > "$b" ]]

if [ "$a" \> "$b" ]

Note that the ">" needs to be escaped within a [ ] construct.
```

`-z`
string is null, that is, has zero length

```
String=''   # Zero-length ("null") string variable.

if [ -z "$String" ]
then
  echo "\$String is null."
else
  echo "\$String is NOT null."
fi     # $String is null.

-n
string is not null.
```

Source: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html

Answer (score 4):

`[` is also a command in Bash so `[ 1 > 2 ]` is the same as `[ 1 ] > 2` which would succeed and create a file named `2`.

As others pointed out you need to use the following syntax to compare integers:

```
[ 1 -gt 2 ]
[[ 1 -gt 2 ]]
(( 1 > 2 ))
```

Comment: Damn, `[ 1 > 2 ]` is really creating a file named `2`! Now I've got one more reason not to use single brace `[` operator. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $(wc -l < f1.txt) -gt $(wc -l < dest/f1.txt) ]; then
    echo -e "f1 has more lines"
else
    echo -e "f1 doesn't have more lines"
fi
```

The -gt will proceed with a numeric compare and not ASCII.