# using nested loop(nested while)

Tags: bash

I have a code where this code goal is if your input match a word in my database it will print the 2nd from the sentence, which is the translation from the 1st word.

The problem is this code print all the 2nd word in the database. I will be very thankful if you can correct me.
this is my code:

```
cari=$(zenity --entry "Masukan Kata Yang Ingin Anda Cari:")
IFS=" " read -ra field <<< $cari
b=(`cat Kamus2.txt | awk '{print $1}'`)
d=(`cat Kamus2.txt | awk '{print $2}'`)
for item2 in ${d[*]}
do
    for item1 in ${field[*]}
    do
        for item in ${b[*]}
        do
            test  "$item1" = "$item" && { echo -n "$item2 "; }
        done
    done
done
echo " "
```

for example database:

```
Aku I
Ingin Want
Roti Bread
Makan Eat
```

the output that i want for example:
if I input `Aku Ingin Makan` the output will be `I Want Eat`

thank you very much for your time and patience

Comment: Can you format the code and put in some snippets rather than image links?

Comment: Please use punctuation marks.

Comment: [For many many good reasons, please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text?cb=1)

Comment: Please replace images with code and add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Answer (score 2):

This is Bash, not C. Use single equal mark for string equality comparison:

```
test "$item1" = "$item" && ...
              ^
```

From `help test` in Bash:

> ```
> STRING1 = STRING2
> ```
>
> True if the strings are equal.

---

You are looping through all three arrays without have any corrrrelation between them. You should instead, use the same index for `b` and `d`:

```
for item in ${field[@]}
do
  for ((i = 0; i < ${#b[@]}; i++))
  do
    if test "$item" = "${b[$i]}"
    then
        echo "${d[$i]}"
    fi
  done
done
```

If you want to put all the output on a single line, use option `-n` for `echo`:

```
echo -n "${d[$i]} "
```

Comment: i have tried using = sir.but it still print the whole 2nd word,not by the spesific input

Comment: Could you replace your test by a if condition? as described in my post?

Comment: still print all the 2nd word sir
what i want is if you input "Aku Ingin Makan" for example the output will be "I Want Eat "

Answer (score 0):

You can read my answer about string comparison in `bash` at this link:

[Why "[ 1 > 2 ]" evaluates to True?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47809065/why-1-2-evaluates-to-true/47809177#47809177)

more especially this part:

**string comparison**

`=`
is equal to

```
if [ "$a" = "$b" ]
```

**Caution

Note the whitespace framing the `=`.**

```
if [ "$a"="$b" ] is not equivalent to the above.
```

`==`
is equal to

```
if [ "$a" == "$b" ]
```

This is a synonym for `=`.

```
Note    
The == comparison operator behaves differently within a double-brackets test than within single brackets.
[[ $a == z* ]]   # True if $a starts with an "z" (pattern matching).
[[ $a == "z*" ]] # True if $a is equal to z* (literal matching).

[ $a == z* ]     # File globbing and word splitting take place.
[ "$a" == "z*" ] # True if $a is equal to z* (literal matching).
```

`!=`
is not equal to

```
if [ "$a" != "$b" ]
```

Comment: i have tried using = sir.but it still print the whole 2nd word,not by the spesific input