# Bash error in linux script. (Command not found)

Tags: bash, shell

I have created a file with the name `pingscript.sh` in Kali Linux included the below codes:

```
#!/bin/bash

if ["$1"==""]
then
    echo "usage: ./pingscrpt.sh [Network]"
    echo "usage: ./pingscrpt.sh 192.168.1"
else
    for x in `seq 1 254`; do
        ping -c 1 $1.$x | grep "64 bytes"
    done
fi
```

but when running it with `./pingscript.sh`, I face the below error:

> ./pingscript.sh: line 3: [==]: command not found

What can be the problem?

Comment: Copy paste your script in [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to fix the syntax errors shown

Comment: see my answer @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47809065/why-1-2-evaluates-to-true/47809177#47809177

Answer (score 3):

Spaces missed in:

```
if ["$1"==""]
```

should be

```
if [ "$1" == "" ]
```